# Azure function to load a blob and send it directly to context.res

Tags: azure-functions

I thought it would be quite easy to load a blob from an azure storage container and write it to the HTTP response, but I'm not able to get it working.

I've declared an input blob like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "resizeImage"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "imageBlob",
      "path": "images/{name}",
      "connection": "ng1_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This is an HTTP trigger, so I just call the URL `resizeImage?name=image1.png` and that provides me with `context.bindings.imageBlob` as the blob data.

However first problem is the blob is the wrong size. I've tried outputting JSON for `imageBlob.length` with the following two images:

1) cat.png = 272228 bytes on disk, but imageBlob.length = 258032 bytes
2) dog.png = 15699604 bytes on disk, but imageBlob.length = 15173390 bytes

So

- I definitely know the file is being found and loaded because these image sizes are close to what they're supposed to be
- I'm guessing `imageBlob` is some kind of stream object? (I see the C# signature is Stream).
- Why is the .length property only giving me about 95% of the image size on disk?

If I try to return it as-is like this then I get a content-length of `imageBlob.length`, but of course the image is incomplete.

```
context.res = {
              body: new Buffer(context.bindings.imageBlob, 'binary'),

              headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'image/png'
              }
```

I will be using the sharp image library to process it, but I can't even right now return the original image! How do I just return the blob as an HTTP response?

Answer (score 2):

I tried saving it right back to Azure with a different filename and it ended up showing as a Content-Type of `Octet-Stream`.

I was then able to search and find that in Javascript apparently the blob doesn't come across correctly unless you specify the type.

So once I added `"dataType": "binary"` the blob came across ok.

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "name": "imageBlob",
  "dataType": "binary",
  "path": "images/{name}",
  "connection": "ng_STORAGE",
  "direction": "in"
},
```

Unfortunately this does not show up in the Azure portal and you have to edit it manually.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/345